# React - Framer motion: prevent initial prop from triggering

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have a basic CRUD application where I'm able to add and remove items on a list, which is animated. This works well with `framer-motion`, but I'm having troubles with the following:

Whenever I delete an item from the list, the following function is called:

```
const handleDeleteFormation = async (id) => {
    await axios({
        method: "DELETE",
        url: `http://localhost:1337/formations/${id}`
    })

    getFormations()
}
```

As you can clearly see, I'm calling the `getFormations()` function after the deletion to re-render the updated list:

```
async function getFormations() {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/formations')
    setFormations(res.data)
    console.log(res.data)
}
```

This will results in a re-render of the list, which is good. But... right after the re-render, the `initial` prop of the `motion.div` will be triggered again which results in conflicting visuals.

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter initial={false}>
            {formations && formations.map((formation, index) =>            
                <motion.div
                    key={formation.id}
                    initial={{ opacity: 0, x: -10 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }} 
                    exit={{ opacity: 0, x: -10 }}
                    transition={{ type: "tween", ease: 'easeOut', duration: 0.2 }}
                >
                    ...
```

My question: is it possible to prevent the `initial` prop from triggering right after the list-update?

Comment: This edit seems quite different from what you were originally asking (preventing animation on page load). The animation shouldn't trigger when the list updates unless the keys are changing. Here's a stripped down example: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-tharp-9vqti?file=/src/App.js

Is it possible that it's actually a child element (without a key) that's animating when the list refreshes?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `<AnimatePresence initial={false}>`.

From the docs:

**[Suppressing initial animations](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/##suppressing-initial-animations)**

> By setting `initial={false}` on AnimatePresence, components present when
> AnimatePresence first loads will start in their animate state. Only
> components that enter after this initial render will animate in.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I tried to apply `initial={false}` but the result remain the same: When changing the page, page 1 for example fades out and simultaneously page 2 fades in (by the changing the opacity). I only want to fade a record in when adding or fade out a record when removing, not when changing the pagination page.